# Can’t display error bars with Plotly and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I’m trying to display error bars on a scatter plot with Shiny and plotly. Here’s my code in my server.R file:

```
data = reactiveVal()

observe({
    results <- data.frame() # actually getting the data from here

    # formatting output
    final.results <- cbind(
        "id" = paste(results$a,
                     results$b,
                     results$c,
                     sep = '-'),
        "sigma" = sprintf("%.5g", results$s),
        "c-e" = sprintf("%.3g",results$calc - results$exp)
    )
    
    data(final.results)
})

output$plot <- renderPlotly(
    as.data.frame(data()[,c("id", "c-e", "sigma")]) %>% plot_ly(
        x = ~`c-e`,
        y = ~id,
        height = 800,
        type = 'scatter', 
        mode = 'markers', 
        marker = list(color = "#90AFD9"),
        error_x = list(array = ~sigma, color = "#000000", type = "data")
    )
)
```

The plot is ok except it’s not showing the error bars, what’s my mistake ?

**EDIT:** clarification for the origin of the `data()` function and what it’s return value is.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's one step from being closed. I'm voting to leave it open for now.

Comment: Thanks for the vote. I updated the question to clarify the context. Hope this will do.

Answer (score 0):

The`sprintf()` function returns a character string, not a number, that is why it is not displaying the `sigma` values as error bars. If you want to keep 5 decimal places, use the `round()` function instead:

```
"sigma" = round(results$s, digits = 5)
```

Comment: I get the idea, but it’s not working any better. Besides, the "c-e" field is the result of an `sprintf` too and the dots are correctly displayed on the graph.

Comment: Ok, my bad, the problem was that even the "c-e" wasn’t treated as numeric values (the round did not fixed it though). I had to set the layout.xaxis.type parameter to linear to get it working : `layout(xaxis = list(type = "linear"))`